# Test if a role inherits another role in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to run a test similar to `IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION()` that returns true if the role returned when calling `CURRENT_ROLE()` inherits a given role. I am looking for this alternative to `IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION()` because it does not appear to be possible to simulate its effect with `POLICY_CONTEXT()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a non-trivial role hierarchy, you would need to write a recursive query against the table "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."GRANTS_TO_ROLES"

If you had a simpler hierarchy (e.g. you know the roles would never be more than 4 steps away from each other) then you could query the same table and just self-join to itself 3 times